# Logical functions over list - Strange python behavior

Tags: python, logical-operators, python-3.8

I have been playing with Python for a while. I recently discovered that when you use the built-in functions `or` and `and` on lists, you get a strange result.

### What I know

According with the
[official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not),
the functions should work as their logical pairs do

[Boolean Operations — and, or, not from (Official Documentation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL5o0.png)

and these operators are, by default, configured for work with `list`.

### The issue (doubt)

The strange thing came when I tried to use these functions with `list`. It happens that the functions seem to be interchanged.

#### How to reproduce it

Separately the functions seem to work fine

```
>>> True and True
True
>>> True and False
False
>>> False and False
False
>>> 
>>> True or True
True
>>> False or True
True
>>> False or False
False
```

We define the lists `a,b` as

```
>>> a = [ True, False, False]
>>> b = [ True, False,  True]
>>> 
>>> a and b
[True, False, True]
>>> a or b
[True, False, False]
```

### Practical

I encountered this problem when trying to create a logical interface for a class utility.
At the end, for some situations, I decided to create a `class Proposition` and overload its operators to receive the expected. But I am left wondering about this behavior.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that the operators would automatically work elementwise over lists? The documentation you linked doesn't say that.

Comment: The link clearly explains what's going on in these examples, once you realise that non-empty lists are considered "true" in Python (and empty ones "false).

Comment: (which is explained in the section above, if you scroll up a bit in the docs)